# What is the meaning of "i" icon on method/class name in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, icons

I just saw a icon "i" along with red square box (which i know for private methods) in one of my class and ultimately it's on a method in the class. It looks like this:

[image]

Can anybody help me what this icon stands for.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: The `i` means there is problem of severity _info_. But I wonder why an `i` is not also displayed at the class. Could you please show the method?

Comment: it's there in the class also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm) section of the Eclipse help this means

> this Java element causes an info problem

It means there is some very minor issue in the method. Open the method in the editor and the Java editor should show more details. The 'Problems' view may also have a message (assuming it is configured to show Info level messages)

Comment: what does it mean. What i need to do.

Comment: @Manish check your method for any minor issue the editor might mention. In my case it was the complexity level of the method that was exceeded.